# Populating multiple colums in R with a loop

Tags: r, loops

I am attempting to create and populate multiple columns (1 for each hour of the day) based on time in and time out. For example:

If time in is 13:00 and time out is 15:00, I want my columns for 13:00, 14:00, and 15:00 to all say 1.

I have created the columns that I needed and they start from [,52]. I am trying to loop through all the rows as follows:

```
for (x in 1:nrow(ed)) {
  start <- c(52+as.numeric(ed$ArrivedHour))
  end <- c(start+c(ceiling(ed$TimeDiff)))
  ed[,start:end] <- 1
}
```

The code is running but hasn't errored out. There are over 200,000 rows in the data set. Is this the correct way of accomplishing this?

Comment: please provide a sample data, your description is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a few ways you could do this without needing to loop. I've added an example using subsetting, which should be much faster than a loop. Although since I have no idea what your data looks like, this will probably have to be adjusted.

```
library(chron)
library(zoo)
#add some example data, time, and two employees
df <- data.frame(time = c("08:00:00", "09:00:00", "10:00:00", "11:00:00", "12:00:00", "13:00:00", "14:00:00", "15:00:00"), eA =c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), eB= c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""))
df$time <- chron(times = df[,1])
df

      time eA eB
1 08:00:00      
2 09:00:00      
3 10:00:00      
4 11:00:00      
5 12:00:00      
6 13:00:00      
7 14:00:00      
8 15:00:00
```

Create a function for the `time in` and `time out`, subset the rows between and fill another row with `1`.

```
timeclock <- function(time.in, time.out) {
df$eA <- 0
df$eB <- 0
time.in = chron(times = time.in)
time.out = chron(times = time.out)
df[df$time >= time.in & df$time <= time.out, 2] <- 1
df
}

timeclock("10:00:00", "14:00:00")
df

      time eA eB
1 08:00:00  0  0
2 09:00:00  0  0
3 10:00:00  1  0
4 11:00:00  1  0
5 12:00:00  1  0
6 13:00:00  1  0
7 14:00:00  1  0
8 15:00:00  0  0
```